# Issue with my API for my App

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

I am reskinning a app I bought. The issue is it came with a API already with it and when I went thru the steps of obtaining an API with Google it don't work with my key,however it works with the one that was already placed when I bought. Any ideas as to why mine will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that after adding the new key you should rebuild the application

Step 1:-In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the  element, by inserting it just before the closing tag :

```
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Substitute your API key for API_KEY in the value attribute. This element sets the key  com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY to the value of your API key, and makes the API key visible to any MapFragment in your application.

Step 2:-  Save AndroidManifest.xml and re-build your application.

Edited .............

I think you have bought an app so the key may be generated in release mode.In my opinon you cannot change the key in release mode.
Key generated in Debug mode can be changed because it is valid for few weeks .So when you bought an app from playstore you cannot modify the key(beacuse It is in release mode)

Comment: @ user3173628 the key I generated is s debug key NOT a release key yet. Should I try to re-key it as a release key? EDITED..... I bought this off codecanyon...

Comment: If you are sure that the key is in debug mode ,you can change the key any time and It should work.
So check whether you followed the steps correctly,because at your first attempt it has worked . check whether the key generated is active .
 when you navigate to google API console,so make sure thatIn the Services page, verify that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
 
 Also check whether this code is added in manifest file:-
 
      <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
  
 check you have enable the wifi or mobile cell data .

Comment: Big help thanks had me worried I got a bad app to reskin

Comment: you can find top rated app in google playstore...try using that..:)....as a suggestion just look this link:-https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapmyride.android2&hl=en

Comment: hey do you have skype

Comment: you do know that I am reskinning apps right? Like I buy the source code redo them and sell em